# Como funciona o algoritmo Conditional Random Fields?

Tags: algoritmo, inteligência-artificial, aprendizagem-de-máquina

Tenho pesquisado a um grande tempo sobre o algoritmo "*Conditional Random Fields*", mas não achei nenhuma explicação profunda sobre seu funcionamento e não consigo entendê-lo. Entendi que ele seria uma modificação da cadeia de Markov (estou certo?), mas não consigo entender seu funcionamento a ponto de ser apto a realizar sua implementação.

Qual seria a melhor explicação didática para o algoritmo "*Conditional Random Fields*"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vamos supor que você goste de acompanhar a cotação diária das ações da sua empresa favorita. Certo dia você percebe uma relação estranha: nos dias em que chove o preço das ações tem mais chance de subir. Intrigado, você busca as informações sobre o clima dos últimos 200 dias, compara com o valor diário das ações e monta esta tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em 40% dos dias não choveu e o preço das ações caiu, em 40% não choveu e o preço subiu, em 8% choveu e desceu e em 12% choveu e subiu.
Com essa tabela você consegue calcular a probabilidade do preço subir dado que choveu no dia:

```
P( S=1|C=1 ) = 12%/(8%+12%) = 60%
```

Sabendo com certeza que vai chover em um certo dia, dá pra prever que o preço irá subir com 60% de chance de acerto. Mas você também percebe que é possível calcular a probabilidade de chover dado que em um certo dia o preço das ações vai subir:

```
P(C=1|S=1 ) = 12%/(40%+12%) = 23,08%
```

Ok, isso não ajudou muito! Ainda não dá pra prever o preço da ações muito bem. Mas se com 2 variáveis aleatórias binárias você conseguiu essa precisão imagine com 300? Se for possível montar esse mesmo tipo de tabela com 300 variáveis aleatórias binárias (que se correlacionem bem com o preço das ações) é muito provável que dê pra fazer uma previsão com mais de 90% de chance de acerto.

Quem dera se isso fosse possível =). Essa tabela é conhecida como a pmf conjunta (joint probability mass function) no caso, das variáveis aleatórias S e C. Cada porcentagem dessa matriz teria que ser representada com uma variável float e para utilizá-la com 300 variáveis aleatórias binárias seria necessário 2^300 floats. Isso é muito mais do que a quantidade de memória de todos os computadores do mundo somada!

Ainda assim, essa matriz conteria toda informação possível de correlação entre as 300 variáveis aleatórias e com ela seria possível prever qualquer uma das variáveis se você tivesse um número suficiente de outras variáveis conhecidas. Estatisticamente se a sua única informação for o valor dessas variáveis, a pmf conjunta é o melhor que tem como ter. Para fazer uma previsão com ela basta somar e dividir os valores certos e de acordo com os teoremas da estatística, não dá pra ter uma previsão melhor.
Sabendo disso muitos métodos tentam compactar essa matriz para se ter uma quantidade menor de dados. Uma forma de compactar funções é a fatoração, por exemplo:

```
f(x,y,z) = g(x,y)*h(x,z)*i(y,z)
```

No caso se a função f for representada por uma matriz de 1000x1000x1000 floats, essa fatoração gera uma representação dessa matriz com 3x1000x1000 floats e dependendo das funções g, h e i escolhidas é possível obter uma aproximação de todos os elementos da matriz f com alta precisão utilizando apenas esses fatores.
Basicamente é isso que o método Conditional Random Fields faz. Primeiro ele considera fixas as variáveis de entrada e de saída, ou seja, com ele se você tiver as variáveis de saída não dá pra inferir as de entrada como na pmf conjunta, mas essa consideração já permite diminuir muito a quantidade de informações necessárias para o método. Já que essa consideração é feita, precisamos apenas de p(y|x) e não da pmf conjunta inteira p(x,y), apesar de ser possível calcular a segunda a partir da primeira com a regra de Bayes. E além disso ele usa a fatoração a seguir para compactar a quantidade de informações na função p(y|x):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo x um vetor com todas as variáveis aleatórias de entrada e y um vetor com todas as variáveis aleatórias de saída. Z é uma função de normalização para que a soma das probabilidades dê 1 e só depende das variáveis de entrada devido à simplificação feita. Os phis são as funções obtidas depois da fatoração.
Agora que temos a forma de fatoração só faltam meios para calcular as funções depois da fatoração com dados de treinamento e fazer as inferências em cima delas. Existe uma teoria muito bem estudada que pode ajudar nisso: a teoria dos grafos. A fatoração mencionada pode ser representada por um grafo bipartido, com dois tipos de nós: os nós redondos que representam as variáveis aleatórias e os nós quadrados representando as funções. Com essa representação vários métodos e algoritmos poderosos da teoria dos grafos podem ser utilizados para ajudar no treinamento e na inferência. A figura a seguir mostra um grafo de uma CRF:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ok, vamos tentar achar a relação mais próxima entre cadeias de Markov e CRF.
A cadeia de Markov é um processo estocástico que apresenta a propriedade de Markov. Existe um modelo gráfico probabilístico chamado de Hidden Markov Model em que os seus nós apresentam a propriedade de Markov, ou seja, você só precisa do estado dos nós vizinhos para inferir o estado de um nó e não do estado de todos os nós da rede. O Hidden Markov model é o equivalente generativo do Conditional Random Fields de cadeia linear que é um modelo discriminativo. Portanto a cadeia de Markov se relaciona com Hidden Markov Model que é um par generativo-discriminativo com o CRF de cadeia linear que é um caso particular do CRF geral. Também existe uma relação entre redes de Markov e CRF, mas resumindo a cadeia de Markov e o CRF não uma relação muito direta.

Além disso é importante esclarecer outra coisa. Conditional random fields não é um algoritmo, é um modelo. As redes neurais, por exemplo, também não são um algoritmo. Redes neurais são modelos e existem vários algoritmos para realizar o treinamento de uma rede neural. Os problemas que queremos resolver são reais, então precisamos de um modelo para trazê-los para o domínio teórico onde possuímos ferramentas para resolvê-lo. A modelagem é isso, um modelo matemático seria por exemplo, descrever um fenômeno qualquer com uma equação que representa a realidade deste fenômeno, resolver a equação já é outra questão. Portanto existem diferentes algoritmos para realizar o treinamento em uma CRF.

Comment: A resposta ainda ficou um pouco incompleta, outro dia eu tento melhorar um pouco o texto e complementar a resposta. Note que a pmf é apenas para casos discretos, para variáveis aleatórias contínuas é usada a pdf, mas ela é mais difícil de explicar.

Comment: Basicamente, a finalidade do CRF então, é diminuir o custo de memória da pmf que você mencionou?

Comment: Não só o custo de memória, mas também o número de dados necessários para treinamento, o tempo de execução do treinamento e o custo para se fazer uma inferência. É isso que os métodos gráficos probabilísticos fazem (CRF é um deles). O ideal é você escolher o melhor modelo para o seu tipo de problema.

Comment: Sérgio você poderia me recomendar alguma material para me aprofundar nos modelos em IA? E principalmente um para me aprofundar no CRF?

Comment: Eu gosto do Machine Learning: a Probabilistic Perspective (Kelvin P. Murphy). Também acho interessante ter uma base forte de estatística, aprender processos estocásticos seria ótimo pra isso (apesar da relação não ser muito direta), mas ainda não conheço um livro muito bom, An Introduction to Stochastic Modeling (Taylor, Karlin) é uma opção. Muita coisa não se aplica a aprendizado de máquinas então talvez seja interessante selecionar capítulos mais importantes.

Comment: Acho que pra aprender Conditional Random Fields o ideal seria ver muita coisa de aprendizagem de máquinas antes. Existem muitas técnicas que pra mim são mais simples e que resolvem bem muitos problemas, como por exemplo: regressão logística, KNN, Learning Vector Quantization, Naive Bayes, Redes de Bayes, PCA e muitas outras...

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado. Vou procurar esse material que você mencionou.

Comment: Parabéns @SérgioMucciaccia, muito boa a resposta! :)